Aligning Sparse Boolean Arrays
I have two (very) long and sparse boolean arrays n1 and n2, representing spikes of two neurons that are responding to the same stimulus. Because they are responding to the same stimulus, they have many "overlapping" spikes (up to some t time-difference); but also because of biological noise they could have uncoupled spikes (tonic properties of each neuron).
I'm looking for a way to map between spikes from n1 and n2, such that:

Each spike from n1 is matched to at most 1 spike from n2.
Each spike from n2 is matched to at most 1 spike from n1.
If two spikes from n2 could match a spike from n1, we take the one occurring closer (in time/array index) to the n1 spike.
We match as many n1 spikes as possible.

I was able to achieve conditions (1), (2) and (4) from above, but I can't find a way to make sure there are no collisions (i.e. 2 n1 spikes mapped to the same n2 spike). Here's what I have:
n1_idxs = np.where(n1)[0]
n2_idxs = np.where(n2)[0]
spike_time_diffs = np.abs(n1 - n2.reshape((-1, 1)))
n2_matches_to_n1 = spike_time_diffs.argmin(axis=0)  # stores the index in `n2` best-matching the spike from `n1`, for each of `n1`s spikes

# assume some predefined value MAX_DIFF
min_spike_time_diffs = spike_time_diffs.min(axis=0)
n2_matches_to_n1[min_spike_time_diffs > MAX_DIFF] = np.nan # disregard matches if the difference is above a threshold

Here's some example input:
MAX_DIFF = 5
n1 = list("000010010100010000000100001")
n2 = list("010010001000101000010000010")

The output should have the same length as number of 1s in n1, and it contains the index of matched spike in n2. Note that my_out contains a collision:
out = [4,8,13,15,19,25]
my_out = [4,8,8,15,19,25]

How can I make sure my mapping doesn't have collisions?

Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please edit your question and post what you have tried so far, including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the full text of any errors or tracebacks, all as formatted text in the question itself. Do not post images of text. The code should be a minimal reproducible example.

Because my initial question didn't contain any example code or input/output. I didn't want to share my code because I feel it's not a good direction; and I can't share data examples because these arrays are very long and very sparse.
@trincot

You could share a reduced example dataset and the output you expect for that data.

Done. On a relative note, could the "AI Assistant" could check for example code/data in the question before publishing it?
